# A post once made community wiki cannot be changed?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I answered a question and by mistake while editing the answer it became community wiki. Now I want to undo the action but there is no such option even if by rolling back it. Cannot it be changed ever? Nobody has edited it yet exept me. So I want to undo. Can I do it by any way? Thank you.

Comment: BTW, as you can see this makes more work for the moderators, so maybe take this one time as an incentive to be more careful in the future? We all occasionally make goofs, but we can all get better at preventing them. :-)

Comment: Yes. I will be careful from future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Undoing a community wiki is a moderator-only thing. If you accidentally made a post community wiki, you can raise a flag on that post. Unless we see a reason why that post ought to be CW, we will undo it.

In this case, though, don't raise a flag, just drop a link to the post here.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3765343/598858. This is the answer.

Comment: Well, Thank you.